# save svm models to file matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have 31 models an I want to save each one in a specific file

this is my matlab function

```
formatspec='model%d'
for k = 1:length(libsvmFiles)
baseFileName = libsvmFiles(k).name;
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
[labels train]=libsvmread(fullFileName);
model=svmtrain(labels,train, '-t 2 -h 0');
file=sprintf(formatspec,k);
save  file model;
```

but the problem is only the first file is saved and its name is 'file' tha's mean the value of the variable `file` is not evaluated

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and badly formatted. Moreover, the problem you encounter has nothing to do with libsvm. I was still able to figure out the problem though. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many Matlab functions, `save` can be used in function form (`save(...)`) or in command form (`save ...`). In the command form that you use, all the arguments are interpreted as strings. That means

```
save file model
```

is equivalent to

```
save('file', 'model')
```

For the second argument that is correct, because you want to refer to the variable with the *name* "model". For the first argument it is wrong, because you want to refer to the file name *contained in* the variable `file`. The correct syntax to use is therefore

```
save(file, 'model')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parens for the save function. The `model` variable also needs to be listed as a string since you need to tell the `save` function the name of the variable, not the variable itself. See Matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html).

`save(file, 'model');`

Additionally you don't have an end to your `for` loop shown, which normally would just throw an error -- however later code might cause this loop to instead only run once. Otherwise you should check your `libsvmFiles` variable as it might be only length 1 or not be an array.

Comment: `model` is the name of the variable to be saved and should therfore be in quotes. see my answer. :-)